# Media query (max-width: 991px) not working at 991px

Tags: css, frontend

I have following rule in my media.css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 991px) {
    .menu nav { display: none; }
    .menu nav ul li {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    }
}
```

It doesn't trigger at width 991px, however at 990px and lower it does. 
I tried to change value to 992px but it breaks my rules totally.

I use bootstrap 3.0 grid system in my html if it matters.

Full html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="touch-menu"><img src="img/menu_icon.png" alt="Меню"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <nav class="menu-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Фотогалерея</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full css:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #01983b;
    background-image: url(../img/header_pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
    inset 0 -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#touch-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
.menu nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu nav ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .menu nav { display: block; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 991px) {
    .menu nav { display: none; }
    .menu nav ul li {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    }
}
```

+js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = $('.menu-nav');

    $('#touch-menu').on('click', function(e) {
        menu.slideToggle();
        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 991 && menu.is(':hidden') ) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Working fine. Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/709uwseg/. I am also using bootstrap in that fiddle.

Comment: *but it breaks my rules totally* and the rules are...?

Comment: Range rules are inclusive.

Comment: By Rules i think he meant by css rules  under that media query.

Comment: I had this exact issue! In my case, the issue was caused by displaying my screen on my external monitor connected with my Windows laptop (through hdmi if it matters). In that scenario, I would get the media queries being off by 1px in exactly the same way you're describing them. However, if I displayed my screen on my laptop monitor, that no longer happened and everything worked normally with the css media queries working exactly as they're supposed to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd the same issue. I solved like that

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 991.5px) {

}
```

So your logic in 992px will not be breaked.

Comment: I like this simple fix.

Comment: Fascinating solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

check `<head></head>` you need meta tag viewport, if have and don't work, show in codepen and i will try to help